# Use CMYK on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to use CMYK colors on my web page. Is there any way to use CMYK in CSS or may be convert CMYK to RGB using JavaScript?

**EDIT:**
I mean I have colors creating algorithm in CMYK notation and I need to use it on web page.

Comment: Just use hex in the first place if you're going to go to the trouble of converting it...do you not have control over the colors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no perfect algorithmic way to convert CMYK to RGB. CYMK is a subtractive color system, RGB is an additive color system.  Each have different [gamuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut), which means there are colors that just cannot be represented in the other color system and vice versa. Both are device dependent color spaces, which really means that what color you really get is dependent on which device you use to reproduce that color, which is why you have color profiles for each device that adjust how it produces color into something more "absolute".

The best that you can do is approximate a simulation of one space onto the other. There is an entire field of computer science that is dedicated to this kind of work, and its non-trivial.

If you are looking for a heuristic for doing this, then the link that Cyrille provided is pretty simple math, and easily invertible to accept a CYMK color and produce a reasonable RGB facsimile.

A very simple heuristic is to map cyan to `0x00FFFF`, magenta to `0xFF00FF`, and yellow to `0xFFFF00`, and black (key) to `0x000000`. Then do something like this:

```
function cmykToRGB(c,m,y,k) {

    function padZero(str) {
        return "000000".substr(str.length)+str
    }

    var cyan = (c * 255 * (1-k)) << 16;
    var magenta = (m * 255 * (1-k)) << 8;
    var yellow = (y * 255 * (1-k)) >> 0;

    var black = 255 * (1-k);
    var white = black | black << 8 | black << 16;

    var color = white - (cyan | magenta | yellow );

    return ("#"+padZero(color.toString(16)));


}
```

invoking `cmykToRGB` with cmyk ranges from 0.0 to 1.0. That should give you back an RGB color code. But again this is just a heuristic, an actual conversation between these color spaces is much more complicated and takes into account a lot more variables then are represented here. You mileage may vary, and the colors you get out of this might not "look right"

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/drCqC/1/)

Answer (score 9):

There's no way to use CMYK in CSS. You can either use RGB or HSL (CSS3 only). Here's a [JavaScript algorithm](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-color-conversion.html) to convert CMYK to RGB (and the other way around).

Edit: the link seems dead now, here's the code from a cached version:

```
/**
*
*  Javascript color conversion
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

function HSV(h, s, v) {
    if (h <= 0) { h = 0; }
    if (s <= 0) { s = 0; }
    if (v <= 0) { v = 0; }

    if (h > 360) { h = 360; }
    if (s > 100) { s = 100; }
    if (v > 100) { v = 100; }

    this.h = h;
    this.s = s;
    this.v = v;
}

function RGB(r, g, b) {
    if (r <= 0) { r = 0; }
    if (g <= 0) { g = 0; }
    if (b <= 0) { b = 0; }

    if (r > 255) { r = 255; }
    if (g > 255) { g = 255; }
    if (b > 255) { b = 255; }

    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
}

function CMYK(c, m, y, k) {
    if (c <= 0) { c = 0; }
    if (m <= 0) { m = 0; }
    if (y <= 0) { y = 0; }
    if (k <= 0) { k = 0; }

    if (c > 100) { c = 100; }
    if (m > 100) { m = 100; }
    if (y > 100) { y = 100; }
    if (k > 100) { k = 100; }

    this.c = c;
    this.m = m;
    this.y = y;
    this.k = k;
}

var ColorConverter = {

    _RGBtoHSV : function  (RGB) {
        var result = new HSV(0, 0, 0);

        r = RGB.r / 255;
        g = RGB.g / 255;
        b = RGB.b / 255;

        var minVal = Math.min(r, g, b);
        var maxVal = Math.max(r, g, b);
        var delta = maxVal - minVal;

        result.v = maxVal;

        if (delta == 0) {
            result.h = 0;
            result.s = 0;
        } else {
            result.s = delta / maxVal;
            var del_R = (((maxVal - r) / 6) + (delta / 2)) / delta;
            var del_G = (((maxVal - g) / 6) + (delta / 2)) / delta;
            var del_B = (((maxVal - b) / 6) + (delta / 2)) / delta;

            if (r == maxVal) { result.h = del_B - del_G; }
            else if (g == maxVal) { result.h = (1 / 3) + del_R - del_B; }
            else if (b == maxVal) { result.h = (2 / 3) + del_G - del_R; }

            if (result.h < 0) { result.h += 1; }
            if (result.h > 1) { result.h -= 1; }
        }

        result.h = Math.round(result.h * 360);
        result.s = Math.round(result.s * 100);
        result.v = Math.round(result.v * 100);

        return result;
    },

    _HSVtoRGB : function  (HSV) {
        var result = new RGB(0, 0, 0);

        var h = HSV.h / 360;
        var s = HSV.s / 100;
        var v = HSV.v / 100;

        if (s == 0) {
            result.r = v * 255;
            result.g = v * 255;
            result.v = v * 255;
        } else {
            var_h = h * 6;
            var_i = Math.floor(var_h);
            var_1 = v * (1 - s);
            var_2 = v * (1 - s * (var_h - var_i));
            var_3 = v * (1 - s * (1 - (var_h - var_i)));

            if (var_i == 0) {var_r = v; var_g = var_3; var_b = var_1}
            else if (var_i == 1) {var_r = var_2; var_g = v; var_b = var_1}
            else if (var_i == 2) {var_r = var_1; var_g = v; var_b = var_3}
            else if (var_i == 3) {var_r = var_1; var_g = var_2; var_b = v}
            else if (var_i == 4) {var_r = var_3; var_g = var_1; var_b = v}
            else {var_r = v; var_g = var_1; var_b = var_2};

            result.r = var_r * 255;
            result.g = var_g * 255;
            result.b = var_b * 255;

            result.r = Math.round(result.r);
            result.g = Math.round(result.g);
            result.b = Math.round(result.b);
        }

        return result;
    },

    _CMYKtoRGB : function (CMYK){
        var result = new RGB(0, 0, 0);

        c = CMYK.c / 100;
        m = CMYK.m / 100;
        y = CMYK.y / 100;
        k = CMYK.k / 100;

        result.r = 1 - Math.min( 1, c * ( 1 - k ) + k );
        result.g = 1 - Math.min( 1, m * ( 1 - k ) + k );
        result.b = 1 - Math.min( 1, y * ( 1 - k ) + k );

        result.r = Math.round( result.r * 255 );
        result.g = Math.round( result.g * 255 );
        result.b = Math.round( result.b * 255 );

        return result;
    },

    _RGBtoCMYK : function (RGB){
        var result = new CMYK(0, 0, 0, 0);

        r = RGB.r / 255;
        g = RGB.g / 255;
        b = RGB.b / 255;

        result.k = Math.min( 1 - r, 1 - g, 1 - b );
        result.c = ( 1 - r - result.k ) / ( 1 - result.k );
        result.m = ( 1 - g - result.k ) / ( 1 - result.k );
        result.y = ( 1 - b - result.k ) / ( 1 - result.k );

        result.c = Math.round( result.c * 100 );
        result.m = Math.round( result.m * 100 );
        result.y = Math.round( result.y * 100 );
        result.k = Math.round( result.k * 100 );

        return result;
    },

    toRGB : function (o) {
        if (o instanceof RGB) { return o; }
        if (o instanceof HSV) {    return this._HSVtoRGB(o); }
        if (o instanceof CMYK) { return this._CMYKtoRGB(o); }
    },

    toHSV : function (o) {
        if (o instanceof HSV) { return o; }
        if (o instanceof RGB) { return this._RGBtoHSV(o); }
        if (o instanceof CMYK) { return this._RGBtoHSV(this._CMYKtoRGB(o)); }
    },

    toCMYK : function (o) {
        if (o instanceof CMYK) { return o; }
        if (o instanceof RGB) { return this._RGBtoCMYK(o); }
        if (o instanceof HSV) { return this._RGBtoCMYK(this._HSVtoRGB(o)); }
    }

}
```

Usage:

To convert from HSV to RGB use library like this:

```
var result = ColorConverter.toRGB(new HSV(10, 20, 30));
alert("RGB:" + result.r + ":" + result.g + ":" + result.b);
```

To convert from RGB to HSV use library like this:

```
var result = ColorConverter.toHSV(new RGB(10, 20, 30));
alert("HSV:" + result.h + ":" + result.s + ":" + result.v);
```

The same goes for CMYK.

Comment: Read title: "RGB-to-CMYK Color Conversion". I need CMYK to RGB

Comment: The link is dead, that's why you shouldn't post answers with links and no actual code.

Answer (score 1):

CMYK support in CSS is currently [considered by W3 for CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#cmyk-colors). But it’s mainly meant for printers and “it is not expected that screen-centric user agents support CMYK colors”. I think you can safely bet that none of the current browsers support CMYK for the screen and therefore you have to convert the colors to RGB somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In the **CSS Color Module Level 4** of the W3C as of 5 November 2019, there is a function called [device-cmyk](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#cmyk-colors) that can be used to define a device dependent CMYK color value.

*Example:*

```
color: device-cmyk(0 81% 81% 30%);
```

The function returns an RGB value that the device calculates by trying to convert the CMYK color to an RGB value that matches the CMYK color as close as possible.

**Note:** I can't find anything regarding the browser support. I guess that no browser is currently supporting this.

Comment: For any future readers: CMYK has been moved to [CSS Color Module Level 5](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-5/#cal-cmyk), it won't come with level 4 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own SCSS/SASS function.
SCSS:

```
@function cmyk($c, $m, $y, $k) {
  $c: $c / 100;
  $m: $m / 100;
  $y: $y / 100;
  $k: $k / 100;
  $r: 255 * (1 - $c) * (1 - $k);
  $g: 255 * (1 - $m) * (1 - $k);
  $b: 255 * (1 - $y) * (1 - $k);
  @return rgb($r, $g, $b);
}
```

SASS:

```
@function cmyk($c, $m, $y, $k)
  $c: $c / 100
  $m: $m / 100
  $y: $y / 100
  $k: $k / 100
  $r: 255 * (1 - $c) * (1 - $k)
  $g: 255 * (1 - $m) * (1 - $k)
  $b: 255 * (1 - $y) * (1 - $k)
  @return rgb($r, $g, $b)
```