# How to export Highcharts with CMYK colors?

Tags: javascript, php, css, svg, highcharts

I would like to know if there is a way to export charts from Highcharts with `CMYK` colors ?
I have read nothing in [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) about CMYK.

I have no problem to export them in `PDF` and also in `SVG` with `php exporting-server` but only with `RGB` colors.

- Do I have to configure something in CSS/Javascript before exporting ?
- Do I have to change something in the page of the exporting server ?

Any suggestions is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I never tried it but I think that this won't be that easy as highcharts is made for charts in web. The export is more like a screenshot but not really made for a perfect printer output. For most of the things you use the export, printed rgb colors are just totally fine. You might be able to find a script that converts your pdf/svg in a second step?

Comment: As the charts are for newspaper, I really need CMYK. I know that RGB conversion to CMYK is not really possible (RGB has less degrees of freedom (3) than CMYK (4)), so I would like to change colors in CSS/Javascript or PHP before exporting (regex if no choice ?). But maybe there is a trick I don't know with highcharts to manage CMYK ?

Comment: The thing is, highcharts works with rgb. A convertion before exporting is still a convertion from rgb to cmyk with all the disadvantages. As far as I know, you can't define your charts directly in cmyk. Btw I think rgb->cmyk works fine (every rgb-color has a corresponding cmyk-color) just the other way arround wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, what I want is not converting RGB to CMYK, but setting a specific CMYK color for any chart element. Life is not easy... :) I'm gonna look for hacks and tell you then.

Comment: It's question not only for Highcharts, but in general for web. As Ria said, Highcharts are designed for web, and if something isn't supported in CSS/JS it won't be supported in Highcharts. See [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869248/use-cmyk-on-web-page) answer, should help you.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the [Highcharts export module](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview) (with PhantomJS) to generate charts **with** cmyk colors. Instead of rgb colors, you just put cmyk values in the options-json, like this:

`"borderColor": "rgb-icc(0%,125%,197%,#CMYK,83.82%,43.76%,0%,0%)"`

If you export as svg, you have a chart in cmyk, which you can use in a cmyk pdf! The browser can't handle this (and shows all colors as black), but that doesn't matter, you have svg with cmyk, and now all you need is a way to convert this to a pdf.

Comment: I cannot test anymore because my job has changed, but nice hack. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just edit the colors in Adobe Illustrator. Even if you could convert to CMYK, there's no telling how that would actually look. You would want to adjust them anyways to get as close to the desired color as possible.